# Loop through queryset and annotate lookup value to records

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to lookup a value, for each record in a queryset, and add that value to the queryset.
I have the following in my view.

```
class InvoiceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    customer_id = Customer.objects.only('ref').get(user_id=user.id)
    
    queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(supplier_id=customer_id.ref)
    
    for invoice in queryset:
        program = FunderProgramMember.objects.get(supplier=invoice.supplier_id, buyer=invoice.buyer)
        invoice.annotate(discount_rate=Value(program.discount_rate))

        return queryset
```

Since the invoices in the queryset could have different discounts, I loop through the queryset and add the relevant discount.

I am receiving the following error: 'Invoice' object has no attribute 'annotate'
I can annotate to the queryset (which doesn't help me since the records in the queryset won't all have the same discount) but it seems I can't annotate to a record in the queryset.

Is there another way of achieving this?
And even if I could annotate to individual record, I am not sure whether those values would be passed with my return queryset?

**EDIT:**
Not sure whether this is the best way of doing it..but it seems to work:

```
class InvoiceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    customer_id = Customer.objects.only('ref').get(user_id=user.id)
    
        queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(supplier_id=customer_id.ref)

        for invoice in queryset:
            program = FunderProgramMember.objects.get(supplier=invoice.supplier_id, buyer=invoice.buyer)
            invoice.discount_rate = program.discount_rate

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`Subquery expressions`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to support this annotation like this:

```
program_discount_subquery = FunderProgramMember.objects.filter(
    supplier=OuterRef('supplier'), buyer=OuterRef('buyer')
).values('discount_rate')[:1]

queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(
    supplier_id=customer_id.ref
).annotate(discount_rate=Subquery(program_discount_subquery))
```

Each invoice in the queryset will then have an attribute `discount_rate`.

Comment: Thank you @Brian Desura. I'll give your solution a try. Please check the edit to my post. I came with something which seems to work without using annotate.

Comment: Yep that will work, but that can be improved and made more efficient. Because you have to hit the database per invoice to get the related `FunderProgramMember`. So if a supplier has 100 invoices, it will require 100 database hits compared to just one.